# Post variable via ajax to mysql db - phonegap

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cordova

I just want to post a simple variable from my phonegap app to mysql database. But it dont work. The db show me empty results.

Mysql database looks like this, Tablename is  `user`

Rows:

```
user (varchar 25),vip (varchar 1),call (varchar 1)
```

At top of my project i inserted:

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tcPlugin.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phoneApp.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/start.js"></script>
```

start.js is my file for the ajax request - the other two working fine so i guess there is not the problem

my start.js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
                  var email = "john@web.de"; 

                  $.ajax({
                         type: 'post',
                         url: 'http://www.blablabla.de/phone/action.php',
                         data: {
                         data: {"email" : email },
                         //data:email,
                         },
                         success: function(result) {
                         console.log(result);
                         }
                         });
```

and my action.php looks like this:

```
<?php
        $dbhost = "bla";
        $dbuser = "bla";
        $dbpass = "bla";
        $dbname = "bla";



$user = $_POST['data']['email'];

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (email)
VALUES ('" . $user . "')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

But everytime i start the app the db is empty. debugger concole is not giving me any errors. db connection is working, tried it with echo connection result. and the other js are working fine.

Comment: you try to print our the POST data like print_r($_POST)? or what is the result?

Comment: change this `data: {
 data: {"email" : email },
 //data:email,
 },`
into this `data: {"email" : email }}, `and try again

Comment: In your ajax call add an 'error' callback and output the response. The 'success' callback will only get called if the response has a 200 status.

Comment: Also check your php.ini file to make sure you are logging and displaying errors. If not add "error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE" and "display_errors = 1"

Comment: @AlexAndrei ive tried your way but still nothing in the db :(.
If i am opening the action.php in my browser its sucessfull and create an empty entry in the db.

Comment: my initial suggestion was wrong, please follow what @renishkhunt proposed and `print_r($_POST)` inside action.php to see if the `$user` variable is populated properly. After that do a `print $sql` to check if the sql query is valid, and test it in the sql editor.

Comment: @AlexAndrei im not a pro coder. im a newbie.
I dont understand what you mean with print_r and print sql

you mean like that?



$user = $_POST['data']['email'];
$user2 = print_r($user);

Comment: i will edit your action.php and post as answer, maybe it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

action.php

```
<?php
        $dbhost = "bla";
        $dbuser = "bla";
        $dbpass = "bla";
        $dbname = "bla";

print_r($_POST); // see full contents of the POST

$user = $_POST['data']['email'];

print PHP_EOL . $user . PHP_EOL; // see full contents of the $user var

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (email) VALUES ('" . $user . "')";

print PHP_EOL . $sql . PHP_EOL; // see the actual sql query, you can test this later in your sql editor ex. phpmyadmin


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

make these edits, run the ajax and check the response tab in the debugger.

Comment: if i run the action.php as single document in browser - it gives me back "Array ( ) INSERT INTO user (user) VALUES ('') New record created successfully". When i run my app, nothing happend in the db. no empty entry and no data anyway.